# How do I get a sub value from this JSON parse?

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to retrieve a specific sub value from a JSON I wrote. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Tour of Honor Bonus Listing",
    "version":"18.1.3",
    "bonuses": [  
       {  
          "bonusCode":"AZ1",
          "category":"ToH",
          "name":"Anthem Tour of Honor Memorial",
          "value":1,
          "city":"Anthem",
          "state":"AZ",
          "flavor":"Flavor Text Goes Here",
          "imageData":"Base64 Text Goes Here"
      },
      {  
          "bonusCode":"AZ2",
          "category":"ToH",
          "name":"Benson Tour of Honor Memorial",
          "value":1,
          "city":"Benson",
          "state":"AZ",
          "flavor":"Flavor Text Goes Here",
          "imageData":"Base64 Text Goes Here"
      }
    ]
}
```

In my BonusTableViewController.swift file I am using the following in my `viewDidLoad` section:

```
let loadedBonuses = loadJson(filename: "BonusData")
print(loadedBonuses as Any)
```

And that `loadJson` function looks like this:

```
func loadJson(filename fileName: String) -> [Bonuses]? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: data)
                print("loadJson loaded JSON")
                return jsonData.bonuses
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The JSON file is called BonusData.json and is located within the app bundle.

The above code works as is, and in the console I get the full output of the bonuses array from the JSON. However I want to have it print just the bonusCode sub value. I tried `print(loadedBonuses.bonusCode as Any)` but I get an error stating,

> Value of type '[BonusTableViewController.Bonuses]?' has no member
>   'bonusCode'

I tried other variants but they all give me the same error. If it helps, the Struct looks like this:

```
// Bonus Data Structs
    struct JSONData: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let version: String
        let bonuses: [Bonuses]
    }
    struct Bonuses: Decodable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageData: String
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, `[BonusTableViewController.Bonuses]` is an array (see the brackets).

You have to use a loop

```
for bonus in loadedBonuses! {
    print(bonus.bonusCode)
}
```

or map the values into another array

```
let bonusCodes = loadedBonuses!.map { $0.bonusCode }
print(bonusCodes)
```

---

Note: The `do - catch` block is pointless as the file is in the bundle and is required to exist. Force unwrap everything. If the code crashes it reveals a design mistake.

```
func loadJson(filename: String) -> [Bonuses] {
     let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")!
     let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
     let jsonData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONData.self, from: data)
     print("loadJson loaded JSON")
     return jsonData.bonuses
}
```

Comment: Regarding the do - catch block, I want to have the app check a server for a newer version of the JSON and then download that and use it. The bundled one may not be the most current one at runtime. So I assume I would need to use the do - catch to check if the downloaded one is newer than the bundled one at some point, and then probably change the path since I assume that a downloaded file would not be "in the bundle" but would be somewhere in the documents container. Does that sound somewhat right, or would the do - catch still not be needed since there is at least the bundled JSON?

Comment: If the file is not in the bundle so it can be changed at runtime then you have to check if it exists and if has the expected format. Everything in the bundle cannot be changed at runtime.